# instruments automation command not working , when executed twice in terminal. i am using xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, automation, instruments

I am using the following command in terminal to trigger my simulator.

```
instruments -w 'iPhone 5s' -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate <app file path> -e UIASCRIPT <script path> -e UIARESULTSPATH <testreport path>
```

For the first time it is working , but when i try to run it the second time in the same terminal window it is throwing the following errors.

> Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 8.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier "com.xxx.yyy"

and also soemtimes the error

> Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 4.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code for running instruments using command line, note that this code is for real devices (TestAutomator is the name of the app, no need to add .ipa):

```
instruments -w 'fa10dec83c62a571a9691b5d9ef24cc68de73bf0' \
-t '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate' \
 TestAutomation \
-e UIASCRIPT '/Users/roykronenfeld/Desktop/Automation.js' \
-e UIARESULTSPATH '/Users/roykronenfeld/Desktop‘
```

And here is a working version for simulator:

```
instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate "/Users/JOHN/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/B9812A59-EBE4-454E-B910-B2969B4D3702/TestApp.app" -e UIASCRIPT ./Tests.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error via an Appium run, which wraps Instruments.

For me, the fix was:

1. XCode > Projects > (My Project) > General
2. In the Identity section, I found errors with my ID and Certificate. I used Xcode prompts to fix both.
3. (Appium specific) Confirm node is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sign info of your project.Generally speaking, the warning message means that the *Instrument* didn't have the authority to run the target application on your device.